# Why does the Array allocation my_arr[0,3] work while my_arr[3,0] fails?

Tags: ruby

I want to pull two values out from an array based on their index.

Unfortunately this fails when the last index is zero and I don't undertand why.

```
my_array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

my_array[1,2]
# => ["b", "c"]

my_array[0,2]
# => ["a", "b"]

my_array[2,0]
# => []
```

Why does the last allocation fail to pull out elements 2 and 0?

I suspect my operation is not in fact doing what I think at all since adding a third index makes the whole thing fail:

```
my_array[1,2,3]
# => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

What am I actually doing with the array[var1, var2] syntax and what should I be doing?

Comment: Did you mean "while `my_arr[3,0] fails?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`my_array[start,length]`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000218) is the *slice* syntax:

> returns a subarray starting at start and continuing for length elements

This is a short syntax for `my_array.slice(start, length);`

You should do this instead:

```
my_array.values_at(2, 0)
=> ["c", "a"]
```

See [`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000254) and [`Array#slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000218)

Comment: Thank you for that - that's what I'd been doing wrong. After reading your answer I re-read the docs and discovered that you can it a little pithier still using `values_at( index1, index2, index3)`

Comment: I was just updating the answer to add `values_at` :)